# Problem with including libraries stored on server

Tags: clion, remote-server

I have a standard set up to work remotely with CLion. I have a header for a library included in my main file(I use the full path) and have a corresponding linking in CMakeLists.txt. The library is stored on server.

The problem is that CLion highlights the header itself as it is not found. Also, all usage cases for functions of the library are highlighted as unknown. 
However, when I upload and build my project remotely, everything works normally and I don't have any issues. But it does bug me to work with a bunch of text highlighted in red.

Thanks!